# SSIS environments and deployment

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012-datatools

I use SQL Server 2012 with Visual studio 2010 with Integration Services Catalog. I would like to know if it is possible to deploy my ssis 2012 project to only one of the three environments I have created. 
I am trying to understand if this is possible or if environments are created only for different variable values (for different test scenarios etc).
So my question is if I can have deployment version 1 on my DEV environment and deployment version 2 on another environment.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.   It's the opposite of what most people want, but you can create a DEV version of your package and only deploy it to your DEV environment, and then create a 2nd version of the package and only deploy it to your 2nd environment.

Note that I am talking about having two separate .dtsx packages, which will have to be maintained separately.   That is what I think you are asking.  If I have misunderstood, then your question wasn't clear.

Comment: Sure, that is exactly what I wanted. Could you help me with this? How can I choose to deploy a package to only one environment?

Comment: How do you deploy packages now?   Pretty much every method of deployment allows deployment to a specific single server.

Comment: I just use the deploy option from ssis. It allows deployment on different servers but not in different environments on the same server.

Comment: How do you have different "environments" on the same server?   What are you calling an environment?   a different database?

Comment: I mean the environments that appear on the Integration Services Catalog, on the SSISDB.

Comment: In that case, I have no idea what you're talking about.   Sorry.